# PHP echo fails but return works?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I have made the below for wordpress plugin `shortcode`, `return` works fine, however `echo/print` doesn't seem to work. `echo/print` isn't present anywhere else in the file so I guess its disabled or something, if that is even possible.

So without the use of `echo/print` how do I compress the below into one `if` statement with a `return` not an `echo/print`. There are 20 subjects in the array `$subjecttitle`, so a more elegant solution would be better.

```
function subjecttitle_func( $atts ){
  $subjecttitle = get_field('gcse_subjects');

  if (!empty($subjecttitle[0])) {
    echo '<h2>' . $subjecttitle[0] .'</h2>'.'<hr></hr>';
  } else { 
    return "";
  } 

  if (!empty($subjecttitle[1])) {
    echo '<h2>' . $subjecttitle[1] .'</h2>'.'<hr></hr>';
  } else { 
    return "";
  }
}

add_shortcode( 'subjecttitle', 'subjecttitle_func' );
```

Comment: if u return from function, then you must echo the fuction

Comment: Do you mean that `echo` doesn't work, or nothing is echoing to the screen? What is calling `subjecttile_func` and what does it expect to be returned?

Comment: subjecttile_func() is returning the shortcode i guess. The plugins a PDF generator so the shortcode is part of a pdf template - I thought that might have something to do with it as nothing is echoed to the PDF.

Comment: Is there a way of parsing the array or something? Still learning here

Comment: Do you want to return one heading at once, or a string with a bunch of <h2>s in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, shortcodes are processed before the_content() is run (which is usually where your shortcode is placed via the cms), so if you echo from there they might appear in strange places. If you search your source code in the browser for what you are echoing, it will probably be there *somewhere*.

Returning the output is the proper way to do it, and you will probably want to do something like:

```
/**
* Create and return the subject title string
*/
function subjecttitle_func( $atts ){

  $subjecttitle = get_field('gcse_subjects');
  $output = '';

  foreach ($subjecttitle as $title) { 
    if ( strlen($title) > 0 ) {
      $output .= '<h2>' . $title .'</h2>'.'<hr />';
    }
  }

  return $output;

}

/** 
* Add the subject title shortcode
*/
add_shortcode( 'subjecttitle', 'subjecttitle_func' );
```

Comment: Bazzinga! That totally worked. I'll need a little while to understand how it works :) Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!!!!

Comment: No problem, it basically loops over the array, and on each iteration it checks that the title is at least 1 character long, if it is it bolts it onto the end of the string, if not then it does nothing and moves on. 

After it has finished looping over the array, it returns the string to wherever called the function.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `implode` For example

```
echo '<h2>' . implode(' - ',$subjecttitle) .'</h2><hr></hr>';
```

which will lead to a single h2-tag with all subject titles at once (separated by a - )
or

```
echo '<h2>' . implode('</h2><hr></hr><h2>',$subjecttitle) .'</h2><hr></hr>';
```

if you want a own h2-tag for each sibjecttitle

Comment: This will work as far as I can see, but you should still be returning rather than echoing from a shortcode.